# Does display:none on images has SEO impact?

Tags: css, seo, search-engine, google-ranking

I am using wookmark.js in order to load Masonry styled grid in my website. As they recommend, I am using first a display:none CSS property to hide images until loading (detected by imagesLoaded) and then display it.

Will it have a bad impact on my website rank by google? can I be punished for using such technique?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with the question?

Comment: SEO questions are off-topic here. You might ask on [webmasters.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: Since seo-bot goes by parsing documents, (v/s use experience), the css properties are ignored. So, irrespective of whether you hide it or not, the image is parsed by the search engine

Comment: I think that this is a very specific question, and not regarding "how to make my website #1 in google". Also, if this is off topic, then the SEO tag in this website should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I can tell, there will be no negative effect of using `display:none;`, and there are no google articles suggesting that it will affect your rep.

Comment: I might add that, this IS about programming as well as SEO, and there is a specific SEO tag on this website, so the question is **ON TOPIC**